# Faster image export with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

In my application the user can seek to a specific position (media.currentPosition), then press the save button, the image will then be exported, here is my ffmpeg command I'm using to achieve this:

```
"-i",Video.mp4,"-filter_complex","[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw:ih[ovr][base];[ovr]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.7[ovrl];[base][ovrl]overlay[v]","-map","[v]","-ss",GetPositionInVideo,"-vframes","1","-q:v","2", "-preset", "ultrafast",directoryToStore+"/"+"Image.jpg"};
```

It is a android application so that is way it is in a string array. The command works perfectly BUT it takes forever to complete.

In my log it will show this repeatedly:

```
[Progress]: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
```

until the frame is reached, then it shows this:

```
[Progress]: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=2.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.00151x
```

it then instantly finishes.

So what I think is happening is, ffmpeg processes each frame until it reaches the desired frame and then processes it.

---

**My question:**

Is there a way to increase the speed/processing time of exporting a single frame from a video to a image? - Perhaps by skipping the unwanted frames and going directly to the frame the user wants to export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"-ss",GetPositionInVideo,` goes immediately before `"-i",Video.mp4` for fast seeking.

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind, if I want to trim a video, should I also put the `-ss` before `-i`? and where should `-to` then be?

Comment: @ClassA Put `-ss` before `-i`, and `-to` *after* `-i`. Note that the semantics of `-to`/`-t` change depending on how you seek. See here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Notes

Comment: @slhck I tried it like that but `-to` gets ignored for some reason. I'm using a video and a image as a input. ShouldI ask a new question?

Comment: @ClassA Best to ask a new question and provide the full, uncut command line output.

Comment: @slhck here is the question I asked - https://superuser.com/questions/1255807/ffmpeg-how-to-achieve-fast-seeking-when-trimming